# How can I show the vertex positions in viewport?

Tags: python

I want to show some Info in the viewport something like vertex indices

[image]

you can see select a vertex and press **N** to see [vertex position](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh) but it's hard.

[image]

so I liked to write a script to show the vertex position

[image]

I tried to use opengl but text was blurry and I couldn't make what I want.

```
# import stand alone modules
import blf
import bpy

font_info = {
    "font_id": 0,
    "handler": None,
}


def init():
    """init function - runs once"""
    import os
    # Create a new font object, use external ttf file.
    font_path = bpy.path.abspath('//Zeyada.ttf')
    # Store the font indice - to use later.
    if os.path.exists(font_path):
        font_info["font_id"] = blf.load(font_path)
    else:
        # Default font.
        font_info["font_id"] = 0

    # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
    font_info["handler"] = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
        draw_callback_px, (None, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')


def draw_callback_px(self, context):

    """Draw on the viewports"""
    # BLF drawing routine
    font_id = font_info["font_id"]
    #blf.position(font_id, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    #blf.size(font_id, 100,100)
    #blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")

    pos = bpy.context.object.location
    v3d = context.space_data
    rv3d = v3d.region_3d
    pos_text = location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, context._center)
    
    blf.position(font_id, pos_text[0], pos_text[1], 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 100,100)
    blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Comment: Related  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139831/overlay-vertex-weights-as-numbers-in-weight-paint-mode  Suggest this could be marked as dupe of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137816/draw-text-with-python-in-3d-coordinate-system   If you are sourcing code from elsewhere add a link for context.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you it's what I want. I just want to show text in 3d viewport I'm wondering why I didn't find that post because I searched a lot!

Comment: @batFINGER I edited my question based on links that you sent me but I don't know why I can't see text in the viewport!!!

Comment: Convert 3d global coords to region coords. The global location of an object is always `ob.matrix_world.translation` which may or may not be `ob.location` See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/how-to-convert-coordinates-from-vertex-to-world-space  New edit are passing `None` as `context` argument, yet trying to use it, which will throw errors to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are passing no context

```
(None, None)
```

but then using some context in `draw_callback_px`
that is `None`

you should use `POST_PIXEL` because it isn't 3d

```
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (bpy.context, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

you forgot to import `location_3d_to_region_2d` libraries

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d
```

Go to `Window > Open System Console` and you will see all the errors
so you can have something to debug what is happening there

[image]

#### convert coordinates from vertex to world-space

Multiply the world matrix by the object-space vector for world space coordinate:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

v = ob.data.vertices[0].co
mat = ob.matrix_world

# Multiply matrix by vertex
loc = mat @ v
```

---

```
import blf
import bpy
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d


def draw_callback_px(context, dummy):
    ob = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

    v = ob.data.vertices[0].co
    mat = ob.matrix_world

    # Multiply matrix by vertex
    pos = mat @ v
    
    v3d = context.space_data
    rv3d = v3d.region_3d
    pos_text = location_3d_to_region_2d(context.region, rv3d, pos)

    blf.position(0, pos_text[0], pos_text[1], 0)
    blf.size(0, 1,1)
    blf.draw(0, str(pos))


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (bpy.context, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

special thanks for @jfranmatheu and [@batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger)

Comment: Good one you got there in the end.  Note using `me.vertices` will most likely not work as expected in edit mode if you start moving them.  Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160913/15543

Answer (score 2):

Although this has become a perfectly legitimate question about scripting, for anybody searching on the title alone, it might be worth pointing out that the shipped add-on *MeasureIt* tools can display vertex locations:

[image]

It's configurable for font size and color, and to show global or local coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for necroposting, but the selected answer seems like it is no more valid. I'm using Blender 3.0.0 and there are a lot of errors thrown around, so I decided to write the script myself. It is my first time creating a script, so pointing out problems in the comments would be useful

Aside from fixing it, I added some additional functionality, like 2 commands to toggle the script, reduced text bloat, display 2 sets of positions (actual vertices with RGBA (0, 0, 0, .5), and bounding box with RGBA (0, 0, 1, 1))

```py
import blf
import bpy
import sys
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d
from mathutils import Vector

handler = None

class Show(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "object.show_vertices_pos"
  bl_label = "Show vertices pos"
  def execute(self, context):
    global handler
    handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (bpy.context, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
    return {"FINISHED"}
class Hide(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "object.hide_vertices_pos"
  bl_label = "Hide vertices pos"
  def execute(self, context):
    global handler
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(handler, 'WINDOW')
    return {"FINISHED"}

bpy.utils.register_class(Show)
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(lambda self, context: self.layout.operator(Show.bl_idname, text = Show.bl_label))
bpy.utils.register_class(Hide)
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(lambda self, context: self.layout.operator(Hide.bl_idname, text = Hide.bl_label))

def pos_to_text(context, pos, color):
  pos = bpy.context.object.matrix_world@pos
  pos_text = location_3d_to_region_2d(context.region, context.region_data, pos)

  blf.position(0, pos_text[0], pos_text[1], 0)
  blf.size(0, 35, 35)
  blf.color(0, *color)
  blf.draw(0, "{0:.1f} {1:.1f} {2:.1f}".format(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z))
def draw_callback_px(context, dummy):
  if bpy.context.object is None:
    return

  box = [Vector((sys.float_info.max, sys.float_info.max, sys.float_info.max)), Vector((sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.min))]

  for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices:
    pos_to_text(context, v.co, [0, 0, 0, .5])
    box = [Vector((min(box[0][0], v.co[0]), min(box[0][1], v.co[1]), min(box[0][2], v.co[2]))), Vector((max(box[1][0], v.co[0]), max(box[1][1], v.co[1]), max(box[1][2], v.co[2])))]

  if len(bpy.context.object.data.vertices) > 0:
    for i in range(2):
      for i_2 in range(2):
        for i_3 in range(2):
          pos_to_text(context, Vector((box[i][0], box[i_2][1], box[i_3][2])), [0, 0, 1, 1])
```